# JMeter: Generate unique csv file then POST

Tags: testing, webserver, jmeter

Completely new to JMeter.

Just wondering if it can be configured to generate a file (i.e. .csv) and then post said file with a HTTP POST?

I've searched a bit on the internet but can't work out whether it is possible...

Reason I want to do this is that I want to test a server that receives data in the form of a .csv file and uploads it to a database. Hoping to test this server by sending a whole bunch of randomised data.

Would be good to have different threads sending different amounts of data at different rates.

Any tips would be amazing, I am a complete newbie.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to upload a file using JMeter HTTP Request sampler.

- JMeter supports beanshell which is Java - scripting language. It can be used to create a CSV file& store it in some path.
- Update the csv file path in the 'Send file with the request' of the HTTP Request sampler.

Comment: thanks, i have gotten this to work using a beanshell pre-processor.